# How can i select <select> <option> when pass an variable in the query string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

suppose i have a select HTML element on the page. how can i select the option after passing a query string. such as computer.php?type=super2 it should select the super2 option in the select

```
 <select>
 <option value="Super">Super</option>
 <option value="Super2">Super2</option>
 <option value="Super3">Super3</option>    
 <option value="Super4">Super4</option>
 </select>
```

can any one help. note: i need a static solution. i am not using any database. althou i am using PHP. any solution based on jquery or PHP ?

Comment: Getting query string param clue from here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values. and setting value for select clue `.val("somevaluestring")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in PHP:

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
$options = array('Super', 'Super2', 'Super3', 'Super4');
echo '<select>';
foreach ($options as $option) {
    echo "<option value='$option'" . ($option == $type ? ' selected' : '') . ">$option</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: thats awesom :) thank you very much.. it works like a charm. :)